# Cannot install Perl Modules on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: perl

I am new to Ubuntu, and for some reason I cannot install any Perl modules. This is my first module install attempt, I believe, fix this and it fixes the rest. hopefully!

```
$ cpanm AnyEvent

 Can't write to /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 and /usr/local/bin: Installing modules to /home/cougar/perl5
 To turn off this warning, you have to do one of the following:
   - run me as a root or with --sudo option (to install to /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 and /usr/local/bin)
   - Configure local::lib in your existing shell to set PERL_MM_OPT etc.
   - Install local::lib by running the following commands

         cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5 local::lib && eval $(perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ -Mlocal::lib)

--> Working on AnyEvent
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-7.15.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Canary::Stability
--> Working on Canary::Stability
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Canary-Stability-2013.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Canary-Stability-2013 ... OK
Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See /home/cougar/.cpanm/work/1559943124.9523/build.log for details.
Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Canary::Stability' is not installed
Bailing out the installation for AnyEvent-7.15.
```

Please help!

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to install from CPAN - rather than using the available Ubuntu package (`libanyevent-perl`)?

Comment: Yes, it is what is needed to run a perl script program, I need certain modules installed and that is the first one.
Strange, they installed easier on windows than Ubuntu, the killer was a module was not compatible with windows, so I have a new drive with Ubuntu. 
Need to get these modules to install.
Something about "Make" folder destination, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When downloading Perl modules with `cpanminus` you must have `make` installed.

```
sudo cpan App::cpanminus
sudo apt install make
```

Also, I had a module that kept failing to install. So I downloaded it, extracted it to its own folder.

Then I navigated to that folder and ran the `make` command.

It told me why it would not install: No GCC Compiler.

Once the compiler was installed, all modules downloaded and installed sucessfully!

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since `/usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1` and `/usr/local/bin` are "System" directories, regular users don't have write access to them.

The easiest fix to to run `cpanm` as `root`, with

```
sudo cpanm AnyEvent
```

Comment: $ sudo cpanm AnyEvent < tried it!

[sudo] password for cougar:
 
--> Working on AnyEvent
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-7.15.tar.gz ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Canary::Stability
--> Working on Canary::Stability
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Canary-Stability-2013.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Canary-Stability-2013 ... OK

Comment: ! Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See /home/cougar/.cpanm/work/1559946694.11696/build.log for details.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Canary::Stability' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for AnyEvent-7.15.

I know and believe it will be a simple fix, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible I have a bad install of Ubuntu?

Comment: It maybe some ftp servers are down, getting 404 on some links.
I believe that would cause installs to fail!
Also I do not care where I get the modules so long as they are the same. and install@

Comment: *********Update****************


Modules have downloaded and installed, just need to tell the OS where they are installed!